# Proving that $f(x)=\frac{x}{|x|-1}$ is a bijection between $\mathbb R$ and $(-1,1)...$

Tags: calculus, analysis, measure-theory

Proving that $f(x)=\frac{x}{|x|-1}$ is a bijection between $\mathbb R$ and $(-1,1)$.

I was only able to prove that it is $"1-1"$ when $x>0$, otherwise, I do not know how to do this...

Comment: I would if I could.

Comment: I think your $f$ is supposed to go from $(-1,1)$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: A couple of trivial observations:  if $x=0$ then $f(x)=0$; as $x$ approaches $1$ from below, $f(x)$ is negative (because its denominator is) and tends to $-\infty$; as $x$ approaches $-1$ from above, $f(x)$ is positive (because both numerator and denominator are negative) and tends to $+\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $f:(-1,1) \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Let $a \in \mathbb{R}$. We want to find $x \in (-1,1)$ such that $f(x)=a$. Thus we need to solve
$$\frac{x}{|x|-1}=a.$$

**Observe:** Since the domain is $(-1,1)$, therefore the denominator is strictly negative. It follows that if $a \geq 0$, then $x \in (-1,0]$ and if $a <0$, then $x \in (0,1)$.

**Case (1):** Let $a \geq 0$.Then by our observation $x \in (-1,0]$. So consider
\begin{align*}
\frac{x}{|x|-1} & =a\\
a|x|-x & = a \\
-x(a+1) & = a\\
x & = \frac{-a}{a+1} \in (-1,0].
\end{align*} 
Similarly,

**Case (2):** Let $a < 0$.Then by our observation $x \in (0,1)$. So consider
\begin{align*}
\frac{x}{|x|-1} & =a\\
a|x|-x & = a \\
x(a-1) & = a\\
x & = \frac{a}{a-1} \in (0,1).
\end{align*} 
This shows that $f$ is surjective.

**For one-one:**

From the observation made above we have $f \geq 0$ when $x \in (-1,0]$ and $f<0$ when $x \in (0,1)$. Thus $f(a) \neq f(b)$ if $a \in (-1,0]$ and $b \in (0,1)$. So you only need to check for one-one on each of those intervals separately. You already mentioned that you have one-one for $x>0$ so same idea will work for $x<0$.